# Why the Coriolis force cannot be a vector in the usual sense?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, parity, coriolis-effect

Why the Coriolis force cannot be a vector in the usual sense?

Comment: In every formulation I have seen of the Coriolis force, it is a vector.

Comment: @CortAmmon It does not transform like a vector under coordinate changes that reverse orientation (wrong sign), they call this sort of thing ["pseudovector"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector).

Comment: Could you, please, specify where you encountered this assertion and in which form it was made?

Answer (score 4):

The Coriolis force on a mass point with mass $m$  and velocity $\vec v$ in a rotating frame with vectorial angular velocity $\vec \omega$ is given by the cross product $$\vec F_C=2m\vec v\times \vec \omega$$ The cross product of two (polar) vectors is a [pseudo-vector or axial vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudovector) because it transforms like a vector under space rotations but changes direction upon space reflections. A normal, polar vector stays the same.

Note: This reasoning holds, as mentioned, when in the rotating frame both $\vec v$ and $\vec \omega$ are polar vectors. When $\vec \omega$ is an axial vector in the rotating frame, as pointed out in the comment below, and $\vec v$ is polar, then $\vec F_C$ is not a pseudo-vector. A similar case is the Lorentz force $\vec F_L=q\vec v \times \vec B$, where $\vec B$ is a pseudo-vector, $\vec v$ is polar and thus the Lorentz force is polar. Thus a doubt of the assertion made in the question that "the Coriolis force cannot be a vector in the usual sense" is warranted.

Comment: But angular velocity is a pseudo-vector.

Comment: @Ben51  - You are right. But the angular velocity $\vec \omega =\vec r \times \vec v_r/|r|^2$  is itself proportional to the cross product of the position vector $\vec r$  and the local frame velocity vector $\vec v_r$ which are both polar vectors. And the triple cross product  for $\vec F_C$  is then the sum of two cross products of polar vectors.

Comment: @Ben51- The explanation in my last comment is not correct because $\vec v_r$ is not in the rotating frame. The assertion that $F_C$ " is not a vector in the usual sense" seems altogether doubtful. I added a note to the answer. Thank you!